# Rails - How to avoid messy conditions in my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still fairly new to rails and trying to learn its 'best practices'. I've noticed when I'm drawing up my views to display a report, my views are starting to look cluttered with if-else-then conditions. If there are some good ways to avoid such mess, please advise.

Comment: Do you have any specific examples that we can work off of?

Answer (score 1):

General advice would be to make sure that any domain logic exists in your models, rather than the view.

Also, extract mark-up into partials if your views are getting too long.

You might also want to look at the MVVM pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll definitely study up on MVVM patterns. I've utilized partials in my views and it does make the initial page cleaner but sometimes can become overly partialed. I guess I have to find some balance in how and when I use the partials.